# Does the max size of an EKS ASG have to be exactly double the min and desired size

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-auto-scaling

I've been told that the max size of my EKS ASG has to be double the min size for when the environment gets rebuilt...but I don't really understand why it has to be exactly double the min size...can anyone explain this...I've been googling without success...I think it's something like this...if I have a min and desired size of 2 and a maximum of only 3..then it could be that there are 2 bad instances and only 1 good instance and then there is not enough space for another 1 good instance to be spun up...is that right?

Comment: Normally that's recommended so that you can spin the new instances up without affecting the capacity of your applications (similar to a blue green deployment) instead of 1 down, 1 up, 1 down, 1 up etc. (a rolling deployment)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary are there any on line resources about this?...I swear I couldn't find any...I mean having the max size exactly double that of the  min and desired not really about blue green deployments

Comment: I haven't particularly googled, it's more of a pragmatic thing